# Emulating a thunderbolt drive backed up by a disk image on a booted mac

Tags: thunderbolt, storage

Is there an way to make a disk image on a booted mac show up as a storage device on the Thunderbolt bus ?

I know it is possible to put the mac in Target Disk Mode and then the whole internal drive shows up as storage device on the Thunderbolt bus, but I only what to share a disk image that way, and I want to keep my mac booted up in macOS.

Technically I believe this is possible. But I'm pretty sure macOS does not ship with appropriate drivers. I also think that it may be do able for a third party to write such driver.

Come to think of it, one way to do this would be to have a Virtual Machine, backed up by the disk image, booting into TDM mode. But I don't know that any VM software has a TDM mode...